# Итератор в собственном классе

Tags: java

Хочу создать итератор в классе `VectorRN`.

Но у меня ничего не выходит, и я вообще не понимаю что нужно делать.

```
// Konstruktor, der erzeugt neues Objekt 
public VectorRn(double[] values) {
    setVector(values);
}

//set Vector
public void setVector(double[] vector) {
    this.values = vector;
}

public static double scalarProd(VectorRn v1, VectorRn v2) { 
    Iterator iter = v1.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; iter.hasNext(); i++) {
            if (i % 6 == 0 )
                res += "\n";
            res += " " + iter.next().toString(); //!!!
        }
        return res;
    return 0;
```

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться в конечном итоге, и зачем вам для этого итераторы?

Comment: Не по теме, но `res` у вас `String`? Как вы хотите возвращать `String` в методе, который возвращает `double`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator` это интерфейс, соответственно ваш класс должен реализовать (`implement`) интерфейс в котором есть 3 метода: `hasNext()`, `next()` и `remove()`

После этого можно уже использовать методы итератора.

[Документация здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Просто реализовать Iterable, Iterator

```
class VectorRn implements Iterable<double>, Iterator<double> {
    //Так как элементы у нас массив, то понадобится счетчик
    private int count = 0;
    //Сделаем метод next()
    public double next() {
        if (count == values.length()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        count++;
        return values[count-1];
    }
}
```

Ну и остальные методы по смыслу.